# Using acceptInsecureCerts with Headless Chrome and Selenium Webdriver, macOS, Rails, Capybara

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, capybara, google-chrome-headless

#### Question

Does headless Chrome work with self-signed certificates via the Selenium Webdriver on macOS?

#### Info

I am attempting to get Rails system tests driven by headless Chrome over SSL.

I have a locally self-signed certificate that I pass the the ruby Puma application server to terminate SSL requests. In order to allow drivers to ignore SSL warnings on the locally signed certificate, I am using the `acceptInsecureCerts` flag to configure the driver capabilities. 
I'm led to believe by [this ticket in Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=721739) that this flag should be recognized as of Chrome 64+.

I can get tests to succeed with Chrome, Firefox, and headless Firefox. Tests do not pass under headless Chrome. I am using (at the time of this writing) what I believe to be the latest versions of Chrome and its variants.

Though folks in the [Chromium ticket](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=721739) appear to be successfully running headless Chrome over locally-signed SSL with the Selenium webdriver, I have not found this to work with the setup described here. If my configuration is correct, then I am unsure if there is a limitation in headless Chrome on macOS, in Selenium webdriver ruby gem, or something else I haven't considered. If anyone has something similar working with Rails on macOS, I'd be interested to learn about your setup.

#### Source

Here is some code to show how I am configuring and running my RSpec/Capybara tests.

Test setup

```
# rails_helper.rb
# ... standard rspec rails helper setup omitted ...

Capybara.register_driver(:headless_chrome) do |app|
  options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(
    args: %w[--headless --disable-gpu --no-sandbox --disable-web-security]
  )
  capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
    acceptInsecureCerts: true,
  )
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
    app,
    browser: :chrome,
    options: options,
    desired_capabilities: capabilities
  )
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each, type: :system) do
    driven_by :headless_firefox
  end
end

module SystemTestHelpers
  def key_file_path
    Rails.root.join("config", "ssl", "ssl-lvh.me.key")
  end

  def cert_file_path
    Rails.root.join("config", "ssl", "ssl-lvh.me.crt")
  end

  def using_app_host(host)
    original_host = Capybara.app_host
    Capybara.app_host = host

    Capybara.server = :puma, {
      Host: "ssl://#{Capybara.server_host}?key=#{key_file_path}&cert=#{cert_file_path}"
    }
    yield
  ensure
    Capybara.app_host = original_host
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include SystemTestHelpers, type: :system
end
```

Sample test

```
# spec/system/welcome_spec.rb

require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.feature "Welcome", :js, type: :system do
  scenario "Visit homepage" do
    using_app_host('https://subdomain.lvh.me') do
      visit "/"

      expect(page).to have_content('Welcome')

      expect(page).to have_content('Your domain: subdomain.lvh.me')
      expect(page).to have_content('Your protocol: https://')
    end
  end
end
```

Page content:

```
<div>
  <h2>Welcome!</h2>

  <p>Your protocol: <%= request.protocol %></p>
  <p>Your domain: <%= request.host %></p>
</div>
```

If I swap out the driver for headless Firefox, configured as below, the tests will pass.

```
Capybara.register_driver(:headless_firefox) do |app|
  options = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Options.new(args: %w[--headless])

  capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox(
    acceptInsecureCerts: true,
  )
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
    app,
    browser: :firefox,
    options: options,
    desired_capabilities: capabilities
  )
end
```

The complete source code for an app that reproduces the issue, and includes the code above is located here: https://bitbucket.org/rossta/system-test-demo.

#### Debug output

Here's a link to some debug output from running the test in either headless Chrome or headless Firefox: https://gist.github.com/rossta/b160204baa87a520e7888c19c8b1ed98.

Note in the output that the session response does not include the 'acceptInsecureCerts' capability for Chrome (test-headless-chrome.log, line 15) while in Firefox we do see the session include the flag (test-headless-firefox.log, line 22).

#### System

- MacOS 10.13.6
- Rails 5.2.1
- Ruby 2.4.1
- `capybara` (gem) 3.5.1
- `selenium-webdriver` (gem) 3.14.0
- `chromdriver-helper` (gem) 2.34
- Chrome 68.0.3440.106. Have also tried

  - Google Chrome 70.0.3524.0 canary
  - Chromium 70.0.3525.0

Comment: Your `using_app_host` method appears to be incorrect since it resets to `server_host` rather than `app_host`

Comment: Also, your demo app that shows the issue isn't publicly accessible.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole
1) Edited `using_app_host`
2) Thanks, updated the permissions.
3) Also, thanks for all your hard work on Capybara!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your log it shows that it's starting chromedriver v2.34. `acceptInsecureCerts` support wasn't added until 2.35 and you should really be running the latest (2.41 currently).  Update your version of chromedriver and things should work.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! That was the one requirement version I forgot to update.

Comment: @rosstaYou're welcome -- I generally prefer to use the `webdrivers` gem rather than `chromedriver-helper` since it always gets the latest version and doesn't break other projects access to `chromedriver` if they don't use `chromedriver-helper`

Comment: Cool, I'll give `webdrivers` a test drive.

Answer (score 0):

caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox

caps['acceptInsecureCerts'] = true